# Select only certain columns from Merged dataframe using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes (excel sheets) and I want to select only certain columns from a resulting `pd.merge`

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('Receivables.xlsx')
#the sheet looks like the table below
```

| ID | Dollar Type | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Receivables | 10 | 20 | 30 | 44 |
| 2 | Receivables | 11 | 21 | 41 | 54 |

```
df2 = pd.read_excel('Payables.xlsx')
#the sheet looks like the table below
```

| Payable_ID | Dollar Type | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Payables | 10 | -20 | -30 | -44 |
| 2 | Payables | 11 | -21 | -41 | -54 |

My merge then looks like this

```
leftJoin = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ID'], right_on=['Payable_ID'], how='left')
```

How do I only select columns `Dollar Type`, `Q1`, `Q2` , `Q3` , `Q4`  from `df1`  and select `Payable_ID`, `Q1`, `Q2` from df2.  The problem I'm running into is that the duplicate columns are appended with either _x or _y. While I get why it's doing that, is there a way to turn off this appending?

In SQL, there's no need for me to specify, for example, df1.[Dollar Type_x] or df2.[Q1_y]

```
SELECT DF1.[DOLLAR TYPE],
   DF1.[Q1],
   DF1.[Q2],
   DF1.[Q3],
   DF1.[Q4],
   DF2.[PAYABLE_ID],
   DF2.[Q1],
   DF2.[Q2]
FROM DF1 LEFT JOIN DF2 ON DF1.ID = DF.PAYABLE_ID
```

Comment: The problem is that merge builds a new dataframe, and that columns should be unique in a dataframe. You can choose how you want to rename the dumplicated columns, but the rename can only add a suffix or keep the original name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass only selected columns of the DataFrames to merge:

```
leftJoin = df1[['ID','Dollar Type','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']].merge(df2[['Payable_ID','Q1','Q2']], left_on=['ID'], right_on=['Payable_ID'], how='left')
```

Now, you have undesired 'ID' column in the merged DataFrame which you can drop using

```
leftJoin.drop(columns=['ID'], inplace=True)
```

You can also make the drop inline with the merge:

```
leftJoin = df1[['ID','Dollar Type','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']].merge(df2[['Payable_ID','Q1','Q2']], left_on=['ID'], right_on=['Payable_ID'], how='left').drop(columns=['ID'], inplace=True)
```

To change the names of the columns, you can use rename:

```
leftJoin.rename(columns={'Q1_x':'Q1', 'Q2_x':'Q2','Q1_y':'Q5','Q2_y':'Q6'}, inplace=True)
```

Which again can be done in the same line:

```
leftJoin = df1[['ID','Dollar Type','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']].merge(df2[['Payable_ID','Q1','Q2']], left_on=['ID'], right_on=['Payable_ID'], how='left').drop(columns=['ID'], inplace=True).rename(columns={'Q1_x':'Q1', 'Q2_x':'Q2','Q1_y':'Q5','Q2_y':'Q6'}, inplace=True)
```